# Can a US employer cut an employee off from a tip pool?

Tags: united-states, labor-law

The Department of Labor [very clearly states](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/flsa/tips) that an employer may not take tip money *for themselves* from employees.  But what if the employer cuts a specific employee off from the tip pool for disciplinary reasons - assuming the entire tip pool is still distributed amongst the other employees and the employer keeps none for themselves?

- Does it change if the employee is or isn't earning a tipped (below minimum) wage?
- If the employee earns tips themselves but has been cut off, are they still required to contribute to the tip pool?

Comment: Now if I gave a $20 tip to an excellent waiter, and I’m told that he isn’t going to get the money, what do you think I will do as a customer? There will be a very loud and ugly disturbance in your restaurant.

Comment: @gnasher729 I hope you aren't assuming I'm the employer here.